# Nikon D70s memory card error. SD Card or Camera?

Tags: nikon, data-corruption

My Nikon camera started acting up like 2 days ago, when it wouldnt take any pictures. I pushed the AE-L AF-L button a few times and it started taking pictures again.
Then yesterday it wouldnt take pictures again. I took out the memory card and put it back in and it started to take pictures again, but then today I tried importing pictures to lightroom through the usb and it would only show previews to about 2 images. When i clicked on those images it wouldnt show full previews they were still blurry.
Also on my camera itself the pictures look corrupted like a tv with a bunch of red blue and green lines going from left to right, and the pictures that look fine in the preview on my camera are actually not when you zoom into them..

Is it something wrong with the camera or with the SD card?

Answer (score 0):

For me this is a problem with SD card. Get new one and try. You can try also to format this card but in this case you will loose all the photos on it

And do you keep all the photos on card? The wise workflow is to shoot a session, then when go home download all the images and format the card.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I actually removed it and put it back in today and most of the images were fine, but the dates were a little messed up. I had about 300 on there, because I didnt delete them after uploading them... probably part of the problem lol

Comment: Think about formatting the card after download all photos. This may help

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I would get the error code, eject the CF and put back in. Sometimes I got error that cause files to be corrupted. Of course this particular error seem to always happen when I was out shooting.

From what I was able to find my best guess it is an issue with CF interface with that camera ( generation ). Looking for that particular issue turned up similar complaints with CF in other models liked D200.

It is still a good camera so I keep as a secondary backup. It might be one of those things where it might be best to use smaller cards and rotate them out.